# If column A contains text, copy value from cell in Column B to corresponding item in Column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet of orders, and I need to copy the price of items to each. For the first instance of each item, I've put the price (like the example below).

How would I go about matching the item in Column A and coping the price from a cell in Column B down to the corresponding cell in the same column?

Example

```
Product Title    | Product Price     |
-------------------------------------
Dress Pattern    | $10.00            |
Pants Pattern    | $7.00             |
Dress Pattern    |                   |
Dress Pattern    |                   |
Pants Pattern    |                   |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: dress_pattern]

1. Select all of column B noting the row number of the first blank cell. In your sample it looks like row 4.
2. Tap <kbd>F5</kbd> then click <kbd>Special</kbd>. Select **🔘 Blanks** and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
3. Type or paste in this formula.
    
     `=vlookup(a4, a$2:b3, 2, false)`
    
    Note that A4 and B3 have to change if your first blank is not in row 4.
4. Tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> together.

Format the new values as currency if required.

[image: dress_pattern2]

Comment: Thanks for your fantastic explanation! I think this has solved my problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your `Product Title` is in `A1` then you need this:

```
Title         | Product Price               
------------- | ----------------------------
Dress Pattern | 10                          
Pants Pattern | 7                           
Dress Pattern | =VLOOKUP(A4,$A$2:B3,2,FALSE)
Dress Pattern | =VLOOKUP(A5,$A$2:B4,2,FALSE)
Pants Pattern | =VLOOKUP(A6,$A$2:B5,2,FALSE)
```

This solution is rather fragile if you intend to ever sort the data. Ideally you would normally have a separate table with the actual prices and you look them all up for this table.

If you work in R1C1 mode then you'd need this:

```
Title         | Product Price                       
------------- | ------------------------------------
Dress Pattern | 10                                  
Pants Pattern | 7                                   
Dress Pattern | =VLOOKUP(RC[-1],R2C1:R[-1]C,2,FALSE)
Dress Pattern | =VLOOKUP(RC[-1],R2C1:R[-1]C,2,FALSE)
Pants Pattern | =VLOOKUP(RC[-1],R2C1:R[-1]C,2,FALSE)
```

(R1C1 mode is much easier to work with, in my opinion.)

Comment: Hello, thanks for you reply. I have a little over 15,000 rows! It doesn't appear to match up any items, but rather just repeat the same price over and over again. Any hints on where I could be going wrong? EDIT: Sorry, I mean it is just repeating the same values of the item moving down the list, rather than matching the name to the correct item and price.

Comment: I've resolved my repeating issue - thank you for your solution. :)